# InDesign: Limit the minimal number of characters in the last line of the paragraph

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting

Is it possible to automatically limit the minimal number of characters in the last line of the paragraph, so that when InDesign Paragraph Composer does its job and hyphenates the paragraph, it ensures that the last line is at least N character wide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eureka! Create a new character style `NoBreak` based on `[None]`. Tick "No Break" for it in "Basic Character Formats". Then in your paragraph styles add a new GREP style so that apply `NoBreak` style to text `.{10}$`. Instead of `10` fill in any number you need as a minimum number of characters in the last line of the paragraph. That's it!

To make the solution more general, one can change regular expression to something like `(?<=.{55}).{10}$`. Instead of `55` fill in an average width of a line in your paragraph measured in  characters. In this case the style will only be applied if a paragraph has more than or equal to `55` + `10` characters in it.

Comment: Be warned that, while it might work for your text, it is not a good *general* solution: it will also get applied to 2-line paragraphs where the second line is very short.

Comment: @RadLexus To make the solution more general, one can change regular expression to something like `(?<=.{55}).{10}$`. Instead of `55` fill in an average width of a line in your paragraph measured in  characters. In this case the style will only be applied if a paragraph has more than `55` + `10` characters in it.

Comment: Yes! That should do nicely, and indeed it depends on the average number of characters/line. You can even pick as many "at least" lines as you want, by using a multiple of the number for your font/size/margins.